# PHP bidimensional array and foreach code iterations

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach

I need to iterate some code in a bidimensional array. In my form there is an input textbox where user insert a date

the array $myArray is

```
Array
(
    [range1] => Array
        (
            [From] => 01/07/2002
            [To] => 31/12/2002
            [Rate] => 10.35
        )

    [range2] => Array
        (
            [From] => 01/01/2003
            [To] => 30/06/2003
            [Rate] => 9.85
        )

    [range3] => Array
        (
            [From] => 01/07/2003
            [To] => 31/12/2003
            [Rate] => 9.1
        )
    .
    .
    .
    .
    [range24] => Array
        (
            [From] => 01/01/2014
            [To] => 30/06/2014
            [Rate] => 8.25
        )

)
```

I want to check in each range (from range1 to range24) if the date inserted by the user is less than [From] or grather than [To] or fall in the range.
Something like:

```
if ($dateInserted >= $myArray[range1][From]) {

        ...do something...

    } elseif ($dateInserted < $myArray[range1][To]) {

            ...do something...

        } else {

            ...do something...

        }

           and so on foreach range
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: how to write the correct foreach

Comment: these operations is a php response of jQuery-Ajax-PHP Form.. I need to make these operations on a server side... I'm able to do these checks with 24 if/else statements, but I would like to shorten my code with a loops.

Comment: here's the right code: $myArray = array( array(From => 1,  To => 10),
           array(From => 11, To => 20),
           array(From => 21, To => 30),
           array(From => 31, To => 40)
          );
      $from = 16;
      $to = 26;
      foreach ($myArray as $ranges) {
       
        if ($from > $ranges['To']) {
         echo "0 - We are out of range, From is greather than range end<br>";
        } elseif ($to < $ranges['From']) {
         echo "1 - We are out of range, To is less than range start<br>";
        } else {
         echo "2 - We are in range<br>";
        }
       
      }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($myArray as $ranges) {
    foreach ($ranges as $data) {

       if ($dateInserted >= $data['From']) {

           #Do Stuff

       } else {


       }

   }
}
```

You get the idea...

Comment: Thanks, now i'm playing with it

Comment: what's wrong with that:  $myArray = array(array(1,10),array(11,20),array(21,30));$test = 16;foreach ($myArray as $ranges) {foreach ($ranges as $data) {if ($test >= $data['0']) {echo "Test is greather or equal than range";
} elseif ($test < $data['1']) {echo "Test is less than range";           } else {echo "Test fall in the range";}}}